# MYSqlDb and Python to play nice together

Tags: python, configuration, config, mysql-python

Disclaimer: I've tried numerous searches and procedures to get this to work as I've found from trying to google this issue, but none seem to work.

I am getting the following when I try to import `MySQLdb` under *Python Interactive Shell*...

```
 Python 2.7.1 (r271:86882M, Nov 30 2010, 10:35:34) 
    [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)] on darwin
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import MySQLdb
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
        (version_info, _mysql.version_info))
    ImportError: this is MySQLdb version (1, 2, 4, 'beta', 4), but _mysql is version (1, 2, 4, 'final', 1)
```

Any suggestions on what to do? I had installed `MySQLdb` via `pip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a Mac, so I can't really test this, however, Mac seems to have problems with this module.  Have you checked out this guy's site? It seems pretty thorough in going through the setup with a Mac.

http://learninglamp.wordpress.com/2010/02/21/mysqldb-python-mysql-and-os-x-a-match-made-in-satans-bum/

Hopefully this helps you out a bit.

Comment: I hadn't seen that before, but i've done some of those steps before. I ended up fixing this, by just resorting to reinstalling django. Thanks for the answer.